# Is there a way to concatenate two fields, using Activerecord? WITHOUT using Virtual Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'd like to join two fields together, preferably with a space in between. I know this can be done at the Model level, but I cannot predict what fields and tables I'll be mixing together, so I can't create a Virtual Attribute for this.

The following is an oversimplificated example of what I'm trying to do.

Tables:

```
# Product (id: integer, name: string, variety: string)
# Location (id: integer, city: string)
```

This would give me a relation of the locations, along with product variety:

```
p=Product.joins(:location).group(:location_id, :variety).pluck(:city, :variety)
```

Now I need to join the location name and the variety name together; that'd be `city` from Location and `variety` from Product.

This is just one example, but there're many more combinations I'd be using that I cannot predict. I'd much rather avoid creating Virtual Attributes for this, as it'd be incredibly complex to add an attribute for each possible combination, and creating its own function withing the affected Models would be a bit too much for something this simple.

Comment: Can you tell us more about your use case? Implementation aside, how would you use it?

Comment: The resulting value would be sent to a sort of "report" page, in the form of a table, where the value here would be in one of the cells. I know this would be better to arrange at the Model level, but due to the complexity of the tables, it is a task I'm not particular fond of taking.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old question, but it came up in a Google search, and I found a better answer.

@philip-hallstrom's answer would work, but it would perform the join in memory. It would be more efficient to perform that join at the database level, like so:

```
Product
  .joins(:location)
  .group(:location_id, :variety)
  .pluck("CONCAT_WS(' ', locations.city, products.variety)")
```

Answer (score 2):

After Rails 6.0 the accepted answer no longer works, you'll get `ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeReference` exception instead. See [this PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/27947) for more details.

Now you would need to use `Arel.sql()` method if you want to pass more to `pluck`.

So, expanding upon @dkniffin's answer, you now need to use:

```
Product
  .joins(:location)
  .group(:location_id, :variety)
  .pluck(Arel.sql("CONCAT_WS(' ', locations.city, products.variety)"))
```

Answer (score -1):

Why can't you simply join the results after plucking?  Like so:

```
p = Product.joins(:location).group(:location_id, :variety).
    pluck(:city, :variety).map{|e| e.join(' ')}
```

Comment: Because it's incredibly inefficient to perform that task with Ruby, rather than doing it directly with the DBMS.